# How to get Total/Available/Used space of a USB drive in MacOS - Swift?

Tags: swift, macos, usb, storage, file-manager

How do you determine the Total, Available, and Used space of a USB drive in Swift (MacOS)?

There are several good posts about this (example: [How to get the Total Disk Space and Free Disk space using AttributesOfFileSystemForpaths in swift 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36006713/how-to-get-the-total-disk-space-and-free-disk-space-using-attributesoffilesystem) and https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlresourcekey/checking_volume_storage_capacity), but they all just get the space of the operating system drive and not of a USB drive.

For example, I have a 64GB USB drive with volume name "myusb", so the MacOS mounts the drive at /Volumes/myusb.  Finder shows the total space of the USB drive as 62.91GB, available as 62.29GB, and used as 625,999,872 bytes.

The trouble seems to be that when I give the path of the USB drive, since it obviously is part of the main / path, it is returning the information for / which is my OS drive, not the USB drive.

Here is what I am doing when trying to determine free space of the USB drive and which returns a value of 292298430687 bytes (which is the available space of my OS drive, not USB drive):

```
/**
   Returns URL of root of USB drive - i.e. /Volumes/myusb
   Uses bundleURL as .app file being executed is located on the USB drive
*/
static func getRootURL() -> URL {
    let bundlePath = Bundle.main.bundleURL
    let bundlePathComponents = bundlePath.pathComponents
        
    let destinationRootPathURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: bundlePathComponents[0])
        .appendingPathComponent(bundlePathComponents[1])
        .appendingPathComponent(bundlePathComponents[2])
        
    return destinationRootPathURL
}

/**
   returns free space of USB drive
*/
func getAvailableSpaceInBytes() -> Int64 {
    if #available(OSX 10.13, *) {
        if let freeSpace = try? getRootURL().resourceValues(forKeys: [URLResourceKey.volumeAvailableCapacityForImportantUsageKey])
                .volumeAvailableCapacityForImportantUsage {
                return freeSpace
        }
    } else {
        // Fallback on earlier versions
        guard let systemAttributes = try? FileManager.default.attributesOfFileSystem(forPath: getRootURL().path),
              let freeSize = systemAttributes[FileAttributeKey.systemFreeSize] as? NSNumber
        else {
            // something failed so return nil
            return 0
        }
            
        return freeSize.int64Value
    }
        
        return 0
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use FileManager's `mountedVolumeURLs` method to get all mounted volumes and get the `volumeAvailableCapacityForImportantUsage` resource key/value from it:

---

```
extension FileManager {
    static var mountedVolumes: [URL] {
        (FileManager.default.mountedVolumeURLs(includingResourceValuesForKeys: nil) ?? []).filter({$0.path.hasPrefix("/Volumes/")})
    }
}
```

---

```
extension URL {
    var volumeTotalCapacity: Int? {
        (try? resourceValues(forKeys: [.volumeTotalCapacityKey]))?.volumeTotalCapacity
    }
    var volumeAvailableCapacityForImportantUsage: Int64? {
        (try? resourceValues(forKeys: [.volumeAvailableCapacityForImportantUsageKey]))?.volumeAvailableCapacityForImportantUsage
    }
    var name: String? {
        (try? resourceValues(forKeys: [.nameKey]))?.name
    }
    
}
```

---

Usage:

```
for url in FileManager.mountedVolumes {
    print(url.name ?? "Untitled")
    print("Capacity:", url.volumeTotalCapacity ?? "nil")
    print("Available:", url.volumeAvailableCapacityForImportantUsage ?? "nil")
    print("Used:", (try? url.sizeOnDisk()) ?? "nil") // check the other link below
}
```

---

For a 16GB USB drive with BigSur installer the code above will print

> Install macOS Big Sur
> Capacity: 15180193792
> Available: 2232998976
> Used: 12.93 GB on disk

---

To get the used space of a volume "sizeOnDisk" you can check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32814710/2303865)

Comment: This worked perfectly. Thank you for the detailed and clear answer

Answer (score 1):

Instead of filtering on the `/Volumes` string, it is possible to use some keys provided by the system to check for external drive.

First, with FileManager's mountedVolumeURLs method, add the option `skipHiddenVolumes`, so that no internal volumes are returned. But you still get `/`.

Second, get resource information on each url for keys like `isVolume`, `volumeIsBrowsable` and `volumeIsRemovable`. If all are true, you most likely have your USB key/drive.

Something like

```swift
let urls = FileManager.default.mountedVolumeURLs(includingResourceValuesForKeys: nil, options: [.skipHiddenVolumes]) ?? []

for url in urls {
    guard let resourceInformation = try? url.resourceValues(forKeys: [.isVolumeKey, .volumeIsBrowsableKey, .volumeIsRemovableKey]) else { continue }
    guard let isVolume = resourceInformation.isVolume, let volumeIsBrowsable = resourceInformation.volumeIsBrowsable, let volumeIsRemovable = resourceInformation.volumeIsRemovable else { continue }

    if isVolume && volumeIsBrowsable && volumeIsEjectable {
        // do something with the URL
    }
}
```